# What is typical interface for WLAN chipset on a modern smartphone?

Tags: spi, wifi, smartphones

Taking into account nowadays Android smartphones support WiFi 802.11ac, what interface is being used for interconnecting of WLAN chipset with Application CPU? Is it SPI or some other? Is it OK to expect that SPI interface will handle such speeds as 400 Mbps and more?

Comment: No, SPI **by far** isn't fast enough to support the full speed of WLAN. Think of SPI as a low speed interface to control ICs and only for low datarate data transfer. A commonly used interface in smartphones is "MIPI", see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPI_Alliance This is just my (educated) guess, this level of technical data is often only available to chipset makers (like Qualcomm) and phone manufacturers.

Comment: After some investigation I admit SPI most likely is not suitable for high speed WLAN host communication.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some random teardown page the Iphone X seems to use a Murata module.
[image]

Murata only has one listed 802.11ac module at their webpage, but you can be pretty sure that Apple gets their own tailor made version. At least this gives a hint on the interface used, USB or SDIO.
[image]

Another module manufacturer like u-blox uses SDIO or PCIe for their "Emmy" or "Nina" Wifi modules.

Comment: So far I hear candidates such as SDIO/ PCIe / USB. However would like to achieve higher confidence level which could be actually used. And I am more interested in Android than iPhone. Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: Well the Samsung S8 seems to have a Murata module with Broadcom SoC: BCM4361

Comment: According to BCM4361 SoC datasheet there are two options for WLAN host interface: SDIO v3.0 and PCIe v3.0. Getting closer.